# In android, what should I do if I run network request in thread but don't want to refresh UI until response comes back?

Tags: android, multithreading, networking

Like I need to check whether a username already existed in database, and the program won't continue until response arrives.

Comment: I think you need to use `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you need asynctask, this is an example how to use it..

```
    public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements YourAsyncTask.YourInterface {


    public YourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your, container, false);



        //do your initial things
        .
        .
        .

        YourAsyncTask yourAsyncTask = new YourAsyncTask(this);
        yourAsyncTask.execute();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onJobFinishListener(YourDataType yourData) {
        //when this method is trigered by your asynctask 
        //it means that you are in ui thread and update your ui component

        //TODO: update ui component with your data
    }
}
```

and this is the asynctask;

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

    private YourInterface yourInterfaceListener;

    private YourDataType yourData; //this data should be calculated in doInBackground method and send via interface

    public YourAsyncTask(YourInterface yourInterfaceListener) {
        this.yourInterfaceListener = yourInterfaceListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        //do your all background tasks here
        .
        .
        .
        yourData = do something here to fill your data..

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        yourInterfaceListener.onJobFinishListener(yourData);
    }

    public interface YourInterface{
        void onJobFinishListener(YourDataType yourData);
    }
}
```

Comment: This interface-way seems more flex and simple. But does ```yourData``` refer to those params that I give to doInBackground() or the response data that I receive? If I need to pass params to the request and also need to receive response data, can you be more specific? Sorry, I'm new to android and Java.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to perform network operations

```
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       /*
        *    do things before doInBackground() code runs
        *    such as preparing and showing a Dialog or ProgressBar
       */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
       /*
        *    updating data
        *    such a Dialog or ProgressBar
       */

     }

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do your work here
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          /*
           *    do something with data here
           *    display it or send to mainactivity
           *    close any dialogs/ProgressBars/etc...
          */
     }
  }
```

And you can execute it using

```
TalkToServer myTask = new MyTask(); // can add params for a constructor if needed
myTask.execute(); // here is where you would pass data to doInBackground()
```

After the network call is done and response obtained `onPostExecute()` is called. If the `AsyncTask` is in inner class of your `activity` you can update UI inside `onPostExecute()`. Otherwise you can use an `Interface` to create a `callback` to `activity`.

You can find `AsyncTask Docs` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use async task. Then you can uae it  your_async_class.execute().get() in your activiry  this ..get method you want to it. Main thread will wait your async task. You have to change your_async_class extends AsyncTask